# multi threading wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

I'm using web refernce call in new working thread in my application as follow:

```
Thread callRunner = new Thread(delegate() 
    { _mediator.IncomingCallDetails(phoneNumber); }); 
callRunner.Start() ;
```

the _mediator calls the web refernce  and replay to the caller in event as follow:

```
void IncomingCallComplited(IncomingCallEventArg args)  
{  
    Caller = args.Caller;  
    Lodgers = args.Lodgers;  
    PreviousMissions = args.PreviousMissions;  
}
```

Caller ,Lodgers and PreviousMissions  are properties of an object that bind to GUI element,as for now the binding works fine and I can see the values from the web reference in screen  my question is should I use Dispatcher in the event or in any other phase ?  and if I do can someone please explain why?
Thanks
Eran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the binding system takes care of that for you, so you don't need to explicitly marshal the call to the UI thread. However, this behavior is not documented (unless I missed it), so I'm not sure you should rely on it...

Also, note that although the `PropertyChanged` event is correctly marshalled across threads by the binding system, the `CollectionChanged` event is **not**. So if you're adding data from another thread to an `ObservableCollection` that is bound to the UI, you need to call `Dispatcher.Invoke`. Or you can use this [custom `ObservableCollection` class](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/), which raises the `CollectionChanged` event on the UI thread

Comment: Thanks Thomas,
it was just what i needed to know